# Getting HTML inline event to work in Chrome extension's popup.js

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to get change detected in `textarea` element, but my JavaScript doesn't work, though it should be working. There are numerous examples done just like this in StackOverflow and I can't figure the problem out.

popup.js:

```
document.getElementById('pasteBox').addEventListener('change', () => {
    console.log("Change detected"); // It's not, this never runs
    var pasteBoxValue = document.getElementById("pasteBox").value
    chrome.storage.sync.set({"pasteBoxValue": pasteBoxValue}, () => {
        console.log("Paste Box changes saved"); // Not even close
    });
});
```

popup.html:

```
<textarea id="pasteBox" rows='3' data-min-rows='3' placeholder='Paste Box'></textarea>
```

I also tried to do the same with a button element, the only difference being the event which was onclick, but nothing happened then either.

Comment: Make sure you're looking at the correct devtools console - the popup has its own window so you need to rightclick it and then `Inspect`.

Comment: @wOxxOm wait, the `Inspect views: background page` link isn't valid? Thanks again for answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answered my question and was provided by wOxxOm:

Make sure you're looking at the correct devtools console - the popup has its own window so you need to right-click it and then Inspect.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "input" event, not "change".